# edit PATH variable using command line in widows 10

Tags: windows, path, command-prompt, system-variable

I was trying to edit %path% variable using command line in windows 10, following [this tutorial](https://cat.pdx.edu/platforms/windows/user-environment/edit-path-variable-in-win-10/), but `pathman/au` was not recognized. What should be the right approach to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to use this tool you need to install Windows resource kit tools ‘pathman.exe‘

Alternatively you can use this directly on the command line:

`setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"`

To add a new path variable to the %path% script. (You can use the option /M for system PATH variable)

I found this reference useful to look through:
https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/